# django-auth Login is not working as expected

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.text import capfirst
from .models import Classname, Sectionname, Teachername, Attendancename

class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': ("Please enter a correct %(username)s and password."
                          "Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."),
        'inactive': ("This account is inactive"),
    }

    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        self.user_cache = None
        super(AuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        UserModel = get_user_model()
        self.username_field = UserModel._meta.get_field(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        if self.fields['username'].label is None:
            self.fields['username'].label = capfirst(self.username_field.verbose_name)

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if username and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
                    code='invalid_login',
                    params={'username': self.username_field.verbose_name},
            )
            else:
                self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)

        return self.cleaned_data

     def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['inactive'],
                code='inactive',
                )

    def get_user_id(self):
        if self.user_cache:
            return self.user_cache.id
        return None

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user_cache
```

views.py:

```
@csrf_protect
@never_cache
def login(request, template_name='login.html',
      authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
      extra_context=None):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = authentication_form(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('student:mains'))

        else:
            print(form.errors)  
    else:
        form = authentication_form(request)

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context)
```

my login template:

```
<html>
<head><title>Login</title></head>
<strong> Mysite Login </strong>
<br><br>
<h3> Please Enter your credentials carefully </h3>
<body>

{% if form.errors %}
    <p>NOT VALID</p>
    {% for errors in form.errors %}
        {{ errors }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Username: </label>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <label>Password: </label>
    <input type="password">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

</body>     
</html>
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^password_change/$', auth_views.password_change, {'template_name': 'password_change_form.html', 'post_change_redirect': '/stu/password_change/done/'}, name="password_change"),
    url(r'^password_change/done/$', auth_views.password_change_done, {'template_name': 'password_change_done.html'}, name="password_change_done"),
    url(r'^restricted/', views.restricted, name='restricted'),
    url(r'^mains/', views.mains, name = 'mains'),
]
```

I'm trying to implement django-authentication on my project. I have read some docs and made the above authentication views and forms.

The problem is that when I'm submitting my login form with correct credentials it doesn't redirect me to the redirect location as specified in my views. It doesn't do anything.

Is it the correct way in which I'm trying to do it? As I'm not using here model form.

Please suggest me the way to correct it...

Thanks! in Advance...

Still facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<form method="post">
<label>Username: </label>
<input name="name">

<label>Password: </label>
<input name="phone">
```

to,

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login_url_name' %}">

<label>Username: </label>
<input name="username">

<label>Password: </label>
<input name="password">
```

Answer (score 0):

Debugging suggestions:

- Make sure you’re hitting the correct view when you submit the form. How? Add debug logging<sup>1</sup> at the beginning of `login()`. If you don’t see the logging when you submit then make sure to set `<form>`’s `action` attribute to proper URL.
- Make sure your form passes `is_valid()` test. Add debug logging inside `if form.is_valid():` branch in your view. If it doesn’t work, make sure credentials are correct. Dump `request.POST` to see what might be wrong with data submitted by the form.

<sup>1</sup> Debug logging may be a simple `Exception("HEYY!!")` in your code. The purpose is simply to see if your code reaches the branch in question. You’ll be sure it does if you see Django yelling at you.